# Run scripts without cron or visit triggers?

Tags: php, joomla, triggers, cron, cpu-usage

Is it possible for Joomla (or Wordpress) to run scripts without cron or visit triggers??

We have this installation that has been using CPU seconds and it's index.php appears in the active processes list of cPanel, but no cron, nor visits are being running. If we rename the index.php file the process disappears, if we resettle it, it re-executes after a few seconds. For some seconds disappears, sometimes appears up to triple WITHOUT having actual visits and no Cron Jobs running.

How is this possible?

We want to know for 2 reasons, security check, and making use of this extra possibility of running scripts if it exists.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for WP, but I can't imagine any way of a script executing on it's own.  I'd suggest looking at the apache logs and perhaps bump up the logging level to see where/how this might be happening.  It sounds to me like your file has been hacked if you CERTAIN that no outside requests are launching it.  In my adventures with hackers, the code is often hidden out of sight, so have a look at it with word-wrapping on and see if you can spot anything - it sounds awfully suspicious to me.

Answer (score 1):

To add, your malicious obfuscated code may actually be in your data store, as is often the case with Magento, Drupal, Joomla and WordPress.

TL:DR Don't just inspect your files, but database records that output HTML too.

You should also open your browsers console and take a look at the network tab. Inspect it for suspicious connections.